# Create "Accepting Options" for the Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a JQuery Plugin but i am having trouble making the options available for the users.
Options Wanted:
AvailableCurrencies: ,
BaseCurrency: ,
DecimalPrecision: ,
Please see the JQuery Plugin Code Below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.tsCurrOptions = function(options) {

    var settingsCurr = $.extend({},
    $.fn.tsCurrOptions.defaults, options);
  };

  $.fn.tsCurrOptions.defaults = {
    AvailableCurrencies: ["GBP", "USD", "EUR", "AUD"],
    BaseCurrency: "GBP",
    DecimalPrecision: 2
  };
  //Customization End
  $(".product-price").after(` < div class = "ts-currency-converter" > </div> `);
    var valuesCurr = $.fn.tsCurrOptions.defaults.AvailableCurrencies;
    var values = valuesCurr;
    console.log(values);
    var baseCurr = $.fn.tsCurrOptions.defaults.BaseCurrency;
    var deciP = $.fn.tsCurrOptions.defaults.DecimalPrecision;
    var values = ["HKD", "USD", "AUD", "EUR", "GBP"]; //Change Currencies Here
    var select = $('<select>').prop('id', 'currency').prop('name', 'currency');
  $(values).each(function() {
    select.append($("<option>").prop('value', this).text(this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1)));
  });

  var label = $("<label>").prop('for', 'currency').text("");

  var br = $("<br>"); $('.header-display-desktop').before(label).before(select).before(br);
  var resultCurr;

  fx.base = baseCurr
  /* 162 Currencies are available - see documentation for more customization*/
  fx.settings = {
    from: fx.base
  }; const currencylocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('Currency'); console.log(currencylocalStorage);
  if (!currencylocalStorage) {
    console.log(currencylocalStorage);
    localStorage.Currency = fx.base;
  }

  $.getJSON('https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/USD',
  function(data) {
    // Check money.js has finished loading:
    if (typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates) {
      fx.rates = data.rates;
      fx.base = data.base;
    } else {
      // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
      var fxSetup = {
        rates: data.rates,
        base: data.base
      }
    }
    /* justtext function*/
    $.fn.justtext = function() {
      return $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();

    };

    /* On pageload Currency */
    var localCurr = localStorage.getItem('Currency');
    $("select#currency").val(localCurr);
    console.log(localCurr);
    $.fn.hentryGrid = function() {
      $('.hentry').each(function PageloadCurr() {
        var self = $(this); // in the next line `this` will get taken over by the `li`
        //Check for sale
        var checkSale = $(this).find('.product-price').children().length;
        console.log(checkSale);
        if ($(this).find('.product-price').children().length > 0) {
          var saleOriginalPrice = self.find('.original-price').text().replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
          console.log(saleOriginalPrice);
          var salePrice = $(this).find('.product-price').justtext().replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
          console.log(salePrice);
          var saleupdateCurr = fx.convert(salePrice, {
            to: localCurr
          });
          console.log(saleupdateCurr);
          var saleTsUpdateCurr = accounting.formatMoney(saleupdateCurr, "", 2, ",", ".");
          console.log(saleTsUpdateCurr);
          var saleOrigina1updateCurr = fx.convert(saleOriginalPrice, {
            to: localCurr
          });
            console.log(saleOrigina1updateCurr);
            var saleOrigina1TsUpdateCurr = accounting.formatMoney(saleOrigina1updateCurr, "", deciP, ",", ".");
            console.log(saleOrigina1TsUpdateCurr + +saleTsUpdateCurr);
            $(this).find(".ts-currency-converter").html(` < div class = "ts-price" > <span class = "ts-orignal-price" > ` + localCurr + `` + saleOrigina1TsUpdateCurr + ` < /span><span class= ts-sale-price>`  + localCurr + ` ` + saleTsUpdateCurr  +`</span > </div> `);
        }
      if(!$( this ).find( '.product-price' ).children().length > 0 ){
        var myTextSub = self.find('.product-price').text();
        console.log(myTextSub);
        var priceTxt = myTextSub.replace(/ [ ^ a - z] / gi, '');
          console.log(priceTxt);
          var localamount = myTextSub.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
          console.log(localamount);
          var localupdateCurr = fx.convert(localamount, {
            to: localCurr
          });
          localupdateCurr = accounting.formatMoney(localupdateCurr, "", deciP, ",", ".");
          console.log(localupdateCurr);
          $(this).find(".ts-currency-converter").html(` < div class = "ts-price" > ` + priceTxt + `` + localCurr + `` + localupdateCurr + ` < /div> `);
          }             
      });
      }
    $.fn.hentryGrid();
    var updateCurr;
    / * On Change Currency * /
      $('#currency').on('change', function () {
      resultCurr = this.value;
      localCurr = resultCurr;
      localStorage.Currency=resultCurr;
      $.fn.hentryGrid();
    });
    / * On Change Variation * /
    $('.variant-select-wrapper').on('data-attribute-changed', function() {
          var data = $('#contains-data').data('text');
          alert('Data changed to: ' + data);
    });
    const targetNode = document.querySelector('.variant-select-wrapper');
      for the observer(which mutations to observe) const config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
      };
      const callback = (mutationList, observer) = >{
        for (const mutation of mutationList) {
          if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
             console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
          } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
             console.log(`The $ {
                  mutation.attributeName
          }
           attribute was modified.`);
           $.fn.hentryGrid();
              }
            }
          };

          // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
          const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

          // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
          observer.observe(targetNode, config);
          //$('.variant-select-wrapper select').on('change', function () {

        });

        $.fn.tsCurrOptions.defaults({
          AvailableCurrencies: ["GBP", "USD", "EUR", "AUD", "CAD"],
          BaseCurrency: "EUR",
          DecimalPrecision: 5
        });
   });
```

I have went through jQuery Documentations and Developed this Plugin following it. But i am not fully clear about this Options part

Comment: What's the use of this platform if nobody gives any help?